# Сохранить последнюю сортировку в bootstrap-sortable

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap, сортировка

Такой вот вопрос, есть таблица с данными, я реализовал постраничный переход с помощью `"limit " + pages + " offset " + count + "), \n"` - в sql запросе, для сортировки использую `bootstrap-sortable.js`, и получается при переходе на следующую страницу с данными, моя `html` перегружается но уже с другой пачкой данных, и заново нужно сортировать, есть ли какая-то возможность в этом плагине чтобы запоминало последнюю сортировку, и чтобы оно автоматически применялась при перезагрузке страницы?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: не скажу про возможности плагина, но скорее всего вам хватит
sessionStorage или localStorage https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: читал про localStorage, но я не пойму как можно туда сохранить состояние столбца в <table> в котором я использую данный плагин для сортировки , это же не просто переменную записать и потом ее на другой странице использовать

Comment: приведите пример данных которые вы хотите сохранить, может я не правильно понимаю вопроса

Comment: мне нужно сохранить не данные а состояние столбца, смотрите я в шапке нажимаю на один из столбцов, происходит сортировка данных по возрастанию, их например 15 записей на странице, потом я нажимаю на вторую страницу, 15 совсем других записей, и сортировка сбрасывается, нужно опять в шапке нажимать на тот столбец заново, надеюсь так понятнее )

Comment: добавил скриншот, вот при нажатии на первый столбец сортировка срабатывает, вот мне бы как-то сохранить состояние этого столбца при перезагрузке страницы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var ths = $('.sortable th:not([data-defaultsort="disabled"])')

  if (localStorage.sort) {
    var sort = JSON.parse(localStorage.sort)
    var th = $('.sortable th[data-sortcolumn=' + [sort.index] + ']')
    if (!th) return
    if (sort.direction === 'up') th.click()
    th.click()
  }

  function saveSort(index, direction) {
    localStorage.sort = JSON.stringify({ index: index, direction: direction })
  }

  $(ths).on('click', function() {
    var index = $(this).attr('data-sortcolumn')
    var direction = $(this).hasClass('down') ? 'up' : 'down'
    saveSort(index, direction)
  })
});
```

Comment: сейчас попробую и отпишусь

Comment: первое что заметил th не назначается класс  sorted, такой класс добавляется td, а второе как понять что страница перегрузилась? Просто по сути это у меня та же страница но уже с новыми данными

Comment: https://drvic10k.github.io/bootstrap-sortable/ я на примере этого плагина смотрел (это не он?)... 
а понимать и не надо когда перезагрузилась страница, просто проверку ставите if (sessionStorage.sortIndex) clickFunction() при этом не забывая удалять данные из sessionStorage, когда пользователь прекращает работать с таблицей... а вообще, было бы неплохо посмотреть на вашу проблему на codepen

Comment: плагин тот, но  правильно применить Ваш код не получается(

Comment: сделайте шаблон на https://codepen.io/

Comment: как-то так, теперь нужно чтобы Вы объяснили как ваш код туда интегрировать https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WYBYxb

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XywoJB?editors=1111
глядите js начиная с 357 строки
плагин расставляет атрибуты, нам нужен data-sortcolumn что-бы понимать какой индекс у текущей нажатой колонки

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86639/discussion-between-sorpok-and-nickolay-rudak).